# IE7 CSS Compatibility

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, compatibility

Let me start off by saying I'm not a web developer and I don't know much at all about comparability.

I've been asked if I can fix a problem with a website in IE7. It loads completely fine in all modern browsers, but they want to make sure it works perfectly in IE7 as well. It technically works fine, but it appears to load the initial content on one pass and then the style on a second pass. I guess I can't be positive if this is what it's doing.

Does anyone who has experience with browser compatibility have any idea if this can be remedied? The website is *extremely* basic, just HTML, CSS, and a little bit of JS.

If this is the case, is there an easy way to set everything to invisible until the page is done loading? I know you can do this with javascript and individual elements.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you saying that the page text and images appear first as unstyled content before the CSS is loaded and renders all the colouring-in afterwards?  Is there a significant delay between these two events?

Comment: If it's just a (minimal) delay in the loading of the stylesheet, don't worry about it. It can happen on other browsers on slower machines. Users of IE are used to a render delay of up to a couple seconds.

Comment: In my opinion it's not a huge deal, but all the people at this company are probably working on very slow machines and it's taking them 5+ seconds to fully load, which is apparently a big deal to them.

Comment: Is this a FOUC? This link may help: http://www.bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include jQuery, put in, `<HEAD>` block:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

Hide the body in your HTML:

```
<body style='display:none'>
```

Unhide the body when the DOM is ready:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() { $(body).show() })
</script>
```

The danger is: if it's slow to load is people will leave before seeing the page.

Comment: Is there an easy way to exempt a block so that a "loading" message can be displayed?

Comment: Actually, the real danger is that a user with JavaScript disabled will never see your website. They'll only see a blank page.

Comment: Eclyps: Yes. Don't hide the body, hide some sort of wrapper DIV for your content and not hide the loading message. Then hide the message and un-hide the main content.

Comment: This works great for everything except FF3, for some reason. This is why I'm not a web developer :)

Comment: You may wish to add a slight delay as well: $(document).ready(function() { window.setTimeout(function() {$(body).show() }},50))

Answer (score 2):

Looks like my comment may have gone unnoticed so I'll throw this down here. This sounds like a Flash of Unstyled Content - a sometimes common occurrence in IE. Check out this site for more information:

[bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/fouc.asp)

Comment: Thanks. The CSS is loaded via link rather than @import. While the problem sounds EXACTLY like what I'm experiencing, the cause doesn't match.

Comment: Bummer, would have been nice to have a quick fix. Glad you found a solution though.